# "setup.py upload" is failing with "Upload failed (401): You must be identified to edit package information"

Tags: python, packaging, setuptools

When running..

```
python setup.py sdist register upload
```

..I get the following output:

```
running register
We need to know who you are, so please choose either:
 1. use your existing login,
 2. register as a new user,
 3. have the server generate a new password for you (and email it to you), or
 4. quit
Your selection [default 1]:  1
Username: example
Password: ...
Registering mypackage to http://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (200): OK
I can store your PyPI login so future submissions will be faster.
(the login will be stored in /Users/dbr/.pypirc)
Save your login (y/N)?y
running upload
Submitting dist/mypackage-1.2.1.tar.gz to http://pypi.python.org/pypi
Upload failed (401): You must be identified to edit package information
```

It's prompting to save the login details, despite `~/.pypirc` already containing this. It then fails to upload files for a package I own, and have full write-access to.

Comment: Same bug is in setuptools for 2.7. Try to use Python 2.6.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Just found [this page](http://www.davidcramer.net/code/python/443/problems-uploading-packages-with-setuptools-on-os-x.html), which solves the issue:

> I also noticed that while it was asking me to save my login information, and I hit Y everytime, it still asked me for the username and password. It turned out that it was saving the information incorrectly as follows:
>
> ```
> [pypi]
> username:dcramer
> password:*******
> ```
>
> Changing it out to this solved the problems:
>
> ```
> [server-login]
> username:dcramer
> password:********
> ```

The above content goes into the [`.pypirc` file](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/packageindex.html#pypirc) in the user's home directory.

Ugh.. I think this may be a good time to give [distribute](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) a try..

Comment: This fix worked for me too, thanks.  Looks like a bug in distutils?

Comment: @Chris Quite likely.. Haven't noticed it lately (might be fixed), but I haven't been using distutils much recently

Comment: I just spent 2+ hours chasing ghosts and got to watch the sun rise through my office window because of fallout from this ridiculous bug.  I am on Python 2.6 btw.

Comment: distribute doesn't help, I encounter same problem with distribute with Python2.7

Comment: Where is that file in which it saves this info? (on Windows?)

Comment: @CraigMcQueen Not sure, but try checking in wherever `os.path.expanduser("~")` shows, or maybe `os.environ['APPDATA']`?

Comment: The file is .pypirc, I found it in the root of my Users folder on Windows (which corresponded to `os.path.expanduser("~")`) but adding the info there didn't fix anything. Removing the [pypi] section caused an error in ConfigParser. Fixed it per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773613/pypi-issues-upload-failed-401-you-must-be-identified-to-edit-package-inform): you need a HOME environment variable on Windows that points to the file's folder.

Comment: The file this is in (for me) was `~/.pypirc`. Might be helpful to note.

Comment: In Windows, if you use Notepad to create the .pypirc file, it will automatically save as `.pypirc.txt`. Use the command line to rename it to `pypirc' without an extension.

Comment: I went round and round with this before finally discovering by accident that HOME was not set to the place it was supposed to be. So I had 2 .pypirc files, one in the place I "knew" was my home folder, because that's the way I set all my machines, and the one that was actually set. The one `python setup.py` was finding was the wrong one. :-/

Comment: Are you saying I need to store my password in plain text in a file?

Answer (score 19):

None of the changes to ~/.pypirc listed here worked for me.

This worked for me, with no changes to ~/.pypirc.  I added "-r https://www.python.org/pypi" to the command line:

```
python setup.py register sdist upload -r https://www.python.org/pypi
```

My ~/.pypirc looks like this

```
[distutils]
index-servers: pypi

[pypi]
username: dlink
password: ******** (the real one)
```

Comment: I can't understand why, but it seems your example operated as suggests. Thank you

Comment: It works even without having a password stored in `.pypirc`. You will be asked instead.

Answer (score 4):

I have the same problem， This is my solution.

The python version is 2.7.7, my windows version is Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1.

here is my .pypirc file

```
[distutils]
index-servers=pypi

[pypi]
repository = https://pypi.python.org/pypi

[server-login]
username = user
password = password
```

**Notice:**

In windows, A file is not allowed named as “.pypirc”，plz，refer to：

[Rename files to empty filename in Windows](https://serverfault.com/questions/22626/rename-files-to-empty-filename-in-windows-vista)

Then put you ".pypirc" file in the same folder with "setup.py"

At last:

run :

```
python setup.py sdist upload
```

or:

```
python setup.py sdist register upload
```

I hope this will be help,thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem and solved it by putting the file .pypirc under my home directory (~/), as the last past of the first comment suggests.

I didn't have the need to modify the name of the section "pypi" of the file pypirc for "server-login", as suggested also in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `[distutils]` to `[pypirc]` as per the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#intermezzo-pypirc-file-and-gpg) and this worked for me.

Here is my `~/.pypirc` file:

```
[pypirc]
index-servers =
    pypi
    pypitest

[pypi]
repository=https://pypi.python.org/pypi

[pypitest]
repository=https://testpypi.python.org/pypi

[server-login]
username:stav
password:****
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, due to my own fault but hopefully this may help someone else who makes this same mistake.

I'm using python 3 on Linux Ubuntu, during registration I issued the setup command using sudo! The result was the .pypirc file in my home directory was owned by root and wasn't readable when trying to perform a module upload immediately after as a none privileged user.

By changing the ownership of the file to myself, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into the same problem. I'm on a new OS X Sierra. Adding [server-login] entry to ~/.pypirc seemed to fix it

http://www.seanbehan.com/how-to-fix-pypi-upload-failed-403-invalid-or-non-existent-authentication-information/

Comment: This is already mentioned in several more complete answers. Also, you answer is borderline link-only.