# PyPi issues - Upload failed (401): You must be identified to edit package information

Tags: python, pypi

Im encountering a problem with pypi similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569315/setup-py-upload-is-failing-with-upload-failed-401-you-must-be-identified-to) one, except that I'm running windows and the mentioned solution page is down.

Does anyone know how to work around this?  I'm using python 2.5.

```
python setup.py sdist register upload

running register
We need to know who you are, so please choose either:
 1. use your existing login,
 2. register as a new user,
 3. have the server generate a new password for you (and email it to you), or
 4. quit
Your selection [default 1]:  1
Username: tschellenbach
Password:
Server response (200): OK
running upload
Submitting dist\django-ogone-1.0.0.zip to http://pypi.python.org/pypi
Upload failed (401): You must be identified to edit package information
```

Comment: Thanks Rick, differences are pointed out in the above question.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

the answer for this seems not very non-windows-specific, give it a try:
[accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1569315/setup-py-upload-is-failing-with-upload-failed-401-you-must-be-identified-to/1569331#1569331) It says basically, that you need a file `.pypirc` with the following section:

```
[server-login]
username:tschellenbach
password:******** (the real one)
```

also, [this is the relevant documentation](http://packages.python.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#intermezzo-pypirc-file-and-gpg) (about `.pypirc`):

> On windows, an you’ll need to set a HOME environ var to point to the directory where this file lives.

Comment: Great :) that works. Pretty lame that thats needed though.

Comment: Could that be caused by the fact that the register command asks for your credentials but the upload command is unable to get them from register?  It would help if you could try this with Python 2.7.  2.5 and 2.6 are too old to get bug fixes, but 2.7 is not.

Comment: This is the documentation about .pypirc: http://docs.python.org/distutils/packageindex

Comment: In Windows, if you use Notepad to create the .pypirc file, it will automatically save as `.pypirc.txt`. Use the command line to rename it to `.pypirc' without an extension.

Comment: You are God bro! That HOME environ thing worked!