# serving a python package from github on pypi

Tags: github, pypi

I have a public python project on github. It's is only meant to be run on windows.
I'd  like to add it to pypi so that people can install it via

```
pip install mypackage
```

Is there a way to store my package on github instead of using an aws s3 bucket?
If yes, how?
I need to also know what's the expected format.
Am I supposed to make a package folder and put mypackage-1.0.tar.gz in it eventhough this is meant for windows?

I've already read this: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/shipping/packaging/

so far, when I run
pip install https://github.com/my_username/mypackage
I get this error:

> Downloading from URL https://github.com/my_username/mypackage
>   Cleaning up... Exception: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg\pip\basecommand.py",
>   line 122, in main
>       status = self.run(options, args)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg\pip\commands\install.py",
>   line 278, in run
>       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)   File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line
>   1197, in prepare_files
>       do_download,   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg\pip\req.py", line
>   1375, in unpack_url
>       self.session,   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg\pip\download.py",
>   line 582, in unpack_http_url
>       unpack_file(temp_location, location, content_type, link)   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg\pip\util.py", line
>   627, in unpack_file
>       and is_svn_page(file_contents(filename))):   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg\pip\util.py", line
>   210, in file_contents
>       return fp.read().decode('utf-8')   File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
>       return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1:
>   invalid start byte

I also figured out that I must write setup.py and setup.cfg and then I can run

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py register
>>Registering mypackage to http://pypi.python.org/pypi
>>Server response (401): basic auth failed
```

I do not know why the registration fails.
Also tried:

```
python setup.py sdist register upload
```

which complains as in:
[PyPi issues - Upload failed (401): You must be identified to edit package information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773613/pypi-issues-upload-failed-401-you-must-be-identified-to-edit-package-inform)
but creating .pypirc did not fix the problem.
Any ideas how to get my package added to pypi?

Answer (score 4):

I found a correct clear documentation: http://peterdowns.com/posts/first-time-with-pypi.html

I list the steps below as well:

- register for pypi account
- put your credentials in a text file .pypirc (on windows you need to rename .pypirc.txt to .pypirc in the terminal)
- set the HOME environment variable (you can do it in the terminal)

  set HOME=path-to-the-directory where you put .pypirc
- make sure you have a correct setup.py and setup.cfg file. You need to read the docs and sample projects.
- make https://github.com/my_username/mypackage/packages/0.1
- build mypackage.zip by running

  python setup.py register -r pypitest
- upload it to you 0.1 folder on github
- tag it in github

  git tag 0.1 -m "Adds a tag so that we can put this on PyPI."
  git push --tags origin master
- register and upload:

  python setup.py register -r pypi

  python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi

Answer (score 1):

I had the same 401 authentication problem: I changed `[distutils]` to `[pypirc]` as per the [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#intermezzo-pypirc-file-and-gpg) and this worked for me.

Here is my `~/.pypirc` file:

```
[pypirc]
index-servers =
    pypi
    pypitest

[pypi]
repository=https://pypi.python.org/pypi

[pypitest]
repository=https://testpypi.python.org/pypi

[server-login]
username:stav
password:****
```